# Can't properly install PyInstaller

Tags: software-installation, python, packaging, python3

Something went wrong while installing, but nonetheless I got a 'success' message:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pyinstaller
[sudo] password for user: 
Downloading/unpacking pyinstaller
  Downloading PyInstaller-3.0.tar.gz (2.7MB): 2.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pyinstaller/setup.py) egg_info for package pyinstaller

    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'bootloader/build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'bootloader/.waf*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'bootloader/waf3-*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader/.lock-waf*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'doc/source'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'doc/source'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'old'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'old'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'tests/scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tests/scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyinstaller)
Installing collected packages: pyinstaller
  Running setup.py install for pyinstaller

    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'bootloader/build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'bootloader/.waf*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'bootloader/waf3-*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader/.lock-waf*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'doc/source'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'doc/source'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'old'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'old'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'tests/scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tests/scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    Installing pyi-bindepend script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pyi-grab_version script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pyi-pprint_toc script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pyinstaller script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pyi-archive_viewer script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pyi-makespec script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pyi-set_version script to /usr/local/bin
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/lib/pefile_py2.py", line 82
        IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG              = 0x80000000L
                                                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed pyinstaller
Cleaning up...
```

After `pyinstaller file.py` there was an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.0', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 99, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 47, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 680, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 156, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 428, in assemble
    imphook_object = ImportHook(imported_name, hook_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 175, in __init__
    self._module = importlib_load_source(hook_modname, self._filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 492, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 539, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1614, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 596, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-Xlib.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import is_unix
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_unix'
```

(by the way, is it normal that I need to use `sudo` with `pip3`, because without `sudo` there I can't install it ?)

Answer (score 0):

The import error is due to some of the modules are not detected by pyinstaller. You have to explicitly add hidden imports for that.
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html Check this out for more information.
You can check which modules has not been imported properly from the warning file generated in build directory of your application.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)